# PHP-FFMPEG On Progress doesn't display until process is finished when encoding a video

Tags: php, ffmpeg, progress-bar, video-processing

Im running PHP-FFmpeg to encode videos which works great.

```
https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg
```

Using their example to get the current progress

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open('test.mp4');

$format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264();
$format->on('progress', function ($video, $format, $percentage) {
    echo "$percentage % transcoded";
});

$video->save($format, 'encoded.mp4');
```

The issue is the progress percentage doesn't display until the encoding is finished which doesn't really help out much. Id like to get the current percentage of encoding as it goes. Im just running this PHP file standalone, maybe I need to do an AJAX call or something to return the data?

Comment: I think you need to flush the output buffer after the echo `ob_flush();`.

Comment: @OnkiHara thank you, I tried adding ob_flush() after the echo and still not echoing out any response. Also tried ob_start() at the beginning and trying flush() and still not getting any response until the script finishes.

Comment: Ok i was able to get it though with ob_implicit_flush(true); & ob_end_flush(); at the beginning of the script so thank you for pointing out the flush! Add this as an answer and i'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked somehow :)